# EditText wont display above ListView

Tags: android, listview, hidden, android-edittext

I have a ListView activity and I want an EditText (and ultimately a button along with it) to display above it.

I believe my xml is fine, but for some reason the EditText is not displaying.  The ListView takes up the entire screen :(

Here's what my XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/newitemtext"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:hint="@string/add_new_item"
    android:maxLines="1"
    />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/inbox_no_items"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas?

Note:  In the layout tab of the xml file in Eclipse, the EditText shows.  When I run my application in the emulator, it does not.

Thank you for your time

Update:

Here is where I set the content view in my onCreate method

```
m_aryNewListItems = new ArrayList<MyListItem>();
m_Adapter = new MyListAdapter(this, R.layout.layout_list, m_aryNewListItems);
setListAdapter(m_Adapter);
```

Here is my extended ArrayAdapter:

```
private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyListItem> {

// items in the list
private ArrayList<MyListItem> m_items;

// constructor
public MyListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<MyListItem> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.m_items = items;
}

// get specific list item
public MyListItem getItem(int position) {
    if (m_items.size() > position) {
        return m_items.get(position);
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}

/*
 * Update screen display
 */
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // get the View for this list item
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_item, null);
    }

    // get the next MyListItem object
    MyListItem lstItem = m_items.get(position);

    // set up the list item
    if (lstItem != null) {
        TextView txtItem = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_itemname);
        TextView txtQty = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_itemqty);
        TextView txtPlace = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_place);

        // set item text
        if (txtItem != null) {
            txtItem.setText(lstItem.getItemName());
        }

        // set qty text
        String strQtyText = "Qty: ";
        if (txtQty != null && lstItem.getItemQty() != -1) {
            BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(lstItem.getItemQty());
            strQtyText += bd.stripTrailingZeros().toString();
            if(lstItem.getItemQtyUnitId() != -1) {
                strQtyText += " " + lstItem.getItemQtyUnitTextAbbrev();
            }
        }
        else {
            strQtyText += "--";
        }
        txtQty.setText(strQtyText);

        // set place text
        if (txtPlace != null && lstItem.getPlaceName() != null) {
            txtPlace.setText(lstItem.getPlaceName());
        }
    }

    // return the created view
    return v;
}
```

}

Comment: Is there any code that is re-arranging the views or possibly the activity is setting a different xml as it's content view?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using the correct xml as the content view.  I've extended ArrayAdapter and made my own.  I'll edit the OP and post the code for my extended ArrayAdapter.

Comment: Updated OP with extended ArrayAdapter definition

Comment: Oh my.  You were entirely correct.  I was looking at the wrong section of my onCreate.  I am setting the content view to another xml file.

Thanks for knockin me on the head :P

Comment: I've been bitten by it myself!

Answer (score 3):

add a `android:layout_weight="1"` to ListView xml

so, this thing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText android:id="@+id/filter"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <Button android:id="@+id/sort"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sort"
            />

        <Button android:id="@+id/add_all"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/add_all"
            />

        <Button android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/add"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <GridView android:id="@+id/myGrid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:verticalSpacing="15dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"

        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:columnWidth="60dp"

        android:gravity="center"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

produces this:

[image]

Comment: hi zed_0xff , can you please tell me how have u arranged the images on gridview.Please tell me the image size and how have you written text on it