# Add Image at above of listview

Tags: android-layout, android-listview, android, android-imageview

I would like to add imageview at above of listview. I knew about add section hearder in listview. But i just wanna save my time so i used image view for listview header instead of using addSectionHeader. Unfortunately i just stuck in with some xml properties. Image Overlay at my list view. Actually image supposed to be at the above of list. Check out my xml layout. Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

[image: Error]

Comment: you want to add image above or below , title says below of listview , description says above of listview !?

Comment: **Update** sorry for my bad. Change already. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this link states the same as of your problem [EditText wont display above ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354241/edittext-wont-display-above-listview)

Answer (score 1):

Use relative layout to have views about or below a listview.

You can tell views to align to top, bottom, left, or right and then have a margin to make room for the other view.

For example, if you want an image below your listview, you would align your listview to parent top and assign a bottom margin to the listview. Then align the imageview to parent bottom and the margin from the listview will make room for it.

Hope this makes sense.

EDIT:

Here is some code: I just wrote this of the top of my head so verify the tag properties but should give you the idea.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Some text"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />  
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Well now after the edit, my answer looks wrong but you can do the same thing with a top margin instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:​

```
TextView tv1=new TextView(context);
Resources res=getResources();
Drawable d1=res.getDrawable(R.drawable.YourImage);
tv1.setBackgroundDrawable(d1);
ListView.addHeaderView(tv1);
```